# UIswitch events in Collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uiswitch

Hi I am trying to write events for UI switch view.

here is my code.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
if(cell.Myswitch.isOn)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"!Alert"
                                                    message:@"Do you want to exit the application?"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
    [alert show];
}
else
{

}
}
```

I declared my UIswitch in collection view cell.But the above action is not working for me.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See [these search results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=nsnull+unrecognized+selector+json).

Comment: Now that you have posted a completely different question, please define "not working". What exactly is the issue? Be specific.